# Move string entries between databases

Tags: c#, database, string, split

I'm splitting a query string using this code:

```
      string y = reader.ReadToEnd();

      Console.WriteLine(y.Length);
      Console.WriteLine(y);
      //Split rows
      string[] x = Regex.Split(y,"\"rows\"");

      Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
      // replace the signs from string x like "}" with a space ""
      x[1] = x[1].Replace("}]}","");
      x[1] = x[1].Replace("\"", "");
      Console.WriteLine(x[1]);
      // split all records from string x wich are seperated by a comma
      string[] r = Regex.Split(x[1], "},{");

      foreach (string s in r)
      {   
          Console.WriteLine(s);
          string[] f = Regex.Split(s,",");

          foreach (string p in f)
          {
              string[] a = Regex.Split(p, ":");

              foreach (string q in a)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(q);
              }   
          }
      }
```

This is the query im using:

```
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(UrlBase + Uri.EscapeUriString("&query=SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 10")) as HttpWebRequest;
```

The results I get back:

```
id
1
firstname
john
lastname
johnson
city
cicago
...
```

What I want to do now is to put these split records into another database.
I have absolutely no clue what to do next so if someone can give me some tips or an example I would be very greatfull.

Comment: although it's not what you asked, what would happen if someone did: &query = delete from person. Google SQL injection

Comment: 1- Check this link for String functions, mainly the `String.Split` and `String.Replace'
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx  
2- There are a lot of samples on the Net (google it) and depends on the database you need to insert to.

Comment: @NeilThompson i dont know how that's relevant and noobob i am asking this question because i couldn't get any wiser about getting it inserted into a database.

Comment: @Kale it's a bit too broad to answer. Here is what I'd do. Pick a database, say it's MySQL. Google for `c# sample insert into MySql` and you will get lots of good hits. Try following a simple sample and see if you get any problems. Usually the process would be: prepare data, open connection, create insert command, attach your data to the command, execute insert command, close connection. Bingo.